# 11 - Disconnects: are they classified as terminals, connectors, both or neither?

Tags: connector, terminal

Disconnects:

[image]

Are they classified as terminals, connectors, both or neither?

Picture shows: bullet, knife, quick-connect

EDIT: revisited this after 6 years of research on the general topic of connectors. Conclusion: I was wrong to try to force disconnects into one of those two classes. Instead, I now see that disconnects are part of a third class: [Single-circuit connectors](https://connectorbook.com/identification.html?m=NNK&n=quick_connect_disconnects) (my site).

Comment: Too broad? I am very specifically asking about each and every one of these rows. Would you be happier if I asked 37 separate questions, one for each row?

Comment: OK, I'll ask 37 separate questions. (Sigh!) I tried to delete this one but I wasn't allowed to. I'll ask one a day. so as not to overwhelm the visitors.

Answer (score 2):

Terminals are where conductors or wires "terminate" and usually, in an electrical context, are a semi-permanent fixture (that requires, for example, a screwdriver to un-terminate). Items 2 and 22 in your list would qualify by that definition.

Everything else appears to be plug and socket style connectors.

Comment: OK, thanks. I believe you said: 2, 22 = terminals; 1, 3~21, 23~37 = connectors.

Answer (score 1):

You'll just have to accept the fact that both "terminal" and "connector" are very broad terms that have a lot of overlap.

Generally speaking, a "terminal" in this context is something that goes on the end of a single conductor (e.g., a wire or PCB trace) in order to facilitate making connections.

A "connector" is a broader term that generally implies a housing that physically supports and insulates one or contacts (or terminals), and may include features such as alignment, strain relief, latching and protection from intrusion.

Comment: Based on that definition, would you be able to please tell me which rows are terminals? Which are connectors? Which both (since you mention overlap)? Which neither?  1 through 15, 30 and 32 all go on the end of a single conductor: are they all "terminals"? Some in rows 1, 2 and 9 have housings: are they "connectors"?

Comment: To be honest, I'd rather put the effort into improving the definition so that you can do it yourself. Maybe I could add it to the tag wiki, too. What is not clear?