# 14 - Bananas and Tips: are they classified as terminals, connectors, both or neither?

Tags: connector, terminal

Bananas and Tips:

[image]

Are they classified as terminals, connectors, both or neither?

EDIT: revisited this after 6 years of research on the general topic of connectors. Conclusion: I was wrong to try to force bananas into one of those two classes. Instead, I now see that bananas are part of a third class: [Single-circuit connectors](https://connectorbook.com/identification.html?m=NNK&n=quick_connect_disconnects) (my site).

Comment: If you are planning on asking 30 different questions of the same type, it's not going to be received well, just a heads up.

Comment: You're telling me! Do you think that I will enjoy asking 30 different questions? I'd rather just have all of them in a single post, but the powers that be have flagged the single post as "too broad". I don't like it one bit either, but what else can I do?

Comment: @Passerby : he might be focussing on the one or two he's struggling with; that's OK. But 30 of these will go the same way as the original. I've seen stackable banana plugs you could call connectors, and line sockets ditto, but the chassis and PCB mount sockets are clearly terminals.

Comment: Thanks Brian. That was very helpful. And, yes. you're correct, I'll focus on the ones I am struggling with.

Comment: Duplicate of [What are the factual names of each of these types of interconnect devices?](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/222273/what-are-the-factual-names-of-each-of-these-types-of-interconnect-devices)

Comment: That post is about every device, this one is only about a particular one. That post was flagged as "too broad", so it's no longer active. That forced me to try to ask individually for each type, individually. I don't like being forced to annoy people with individual posts, but I am at the mercy of editors.

Comment: Then edit that one to the (surely not many) you have trouble with. And ask for it to be reopened.But if this really is "for publication" a reference to a SE question as a source will likely seriously damage the publication's credibility.

Comment: OK. I'll do that.

Comment: Just curious, but why do you care about the classification unless you are designing a catalogue? You could get a good idea of their classification from looking at the catalogues of the main suppliers, Farnell, RS, Mouser, Digikey, etc.

Comment: No, I am not designing a catalog. Vendors' catalog and manufacturers' sites are mutually inconsistent, and even self-inconsistent.

Comment: You acknowledge that catalogs and web sites have differing opinions on this subject, so what makes you think you're going to get any consistent answers here? I think that what you should do is fine someone who has some experience with connectors--maybe an engineer but perhaps a salesperson or account manager who works for a company that makes connectors--and ask that person to give you a view that, while not gospel, will at least be consistent with itself. Maybe offer to buy the person lunch. :-)

Comment: > what makes you think you're going to get any consistent answers here? // I'll settle for *any* answer, At this point all I got is grief from various editors, valid questions from people like you (thank you) but very little in actual answers. "Consistent" is a moot point when you don't get enough answers to compare them for consistency.

Comment: @DavideAndrea I'm not going to humor this question iterated over an interconnect catalog.

Answer (score 2):

According to definitions of "Connector" and "Terminal" given in wikipedia:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_connector

> An electrical connector is an electro-mechanical device for joining electrical circuits as an interface using a mechanical assembly....

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_(electronics)

> A terminal is the point at which a conductor from an electrical component, device or network comes to an end and provides a point of connection to external circuits. A terminal may simply be the end of a wire or it **may be fitted with a connector** *[emphasis mine]* or fastener....

The key functional difference is not the actual metal-and-plastic part itself, but rather **how it is used in the system**.

If for example I design a PCB that brings out a set of electrical signals to a row of header pins, those would be considered "Terminals" (I might even call them "Test Points" if these are meant to support any type of diagnostic testing.)

But if I then design a second PCB that uses a row of receptacle pins that mate with the header pins of the first board, now both the receptacle and the header pins would be considered "Connectors".